# Unable to invoke constructor for AuthenticationResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, authentication

I'm trying to create a dummy object of `AuthenticationResult` (a sealed class) from the package `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` in a public method in a `.NET Core 2.1` project.

What I've tried?

1. Tried to invoke the constructor via :

   ```
   BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

   CultureInfo culture = null;

   AuthenticationResult auth = (AuthenticationResult)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AuthenticationResult),
               flags, null, new object[] { "a", "b", "c", DateTimeOffset.MinValue }, culture);
   ```

It throws the following error:
`System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult' not found.`

2. Tried to create a dynamic object and cast it to AuthenticationResult, this also failed with message unable to find a constructor. I'm inclined towards using method 1 for object creation.

I didn't find any construction definition on the official docs but the same syntax (from method 1) is being used in another parts of the System with no differences to any of the given arguments/variables and it's running fine. I'm unable to find the author of the same.

**So, please can you suggest why is it throwing the error and what is the right way to call `AuthenticationResult`'s constructor or create its dummy object?**

**Update 1:**

Another method (similar to method 2):

```
        using (Stream r = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            string s = new StreamReader(r).ReadToEnd();
            ar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationResult>(s);
        }

JSON parsed:
{
  "AccessToken": "b",
  "AccessTokenType": "a",
  "ExpiresOn": "2020-07-15T12:38:13Z",
  "IdToken": null,
  "IsMultipleResourceRefreshToken": false,
  "RefreshToken": "c",
  "TenantId": null,
  "UserInfo": null
}
```

Error thrown:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'AccessToken', line 2, position 16.`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Is it for unit testing?

Comment: @Neil Yes, right.

Comment: Update to Core 3x.  Code uses TLS for authentication and TLS 1.0/1.1 was discontinued in June of this year.  You must use TLS 1.2 or later.  Also you must update any APIs (dll) to versions that support TLS 1.2.  You code also has to be updated to specify TLS 1.2 so you don't use the default which may be 1.0 or 1.1.  I've been answer similar issues almost daily for the last 3 weeks.  Looks like many companies pushed Microsoft monthly security patches at the end of July that made TLS 1.0/1.1 obsolete.

Comment: @jdweng Can't, the system can only support 2.1 at the moment.

Comment: Can you deserialise some json into it?

Comment: Read my updates to last comment.   You do not have any choice unless you back out the Microsoft Security Patches.  You may be able to change a registry setting.  Not sure.  People have been warned about this change 5 years ago.

Comment: @jdweng OP is trying to write some unit tests for existing code (that might not have changed since it was written 2 years ago). Why has that got anything to do with upgrading authentication packages?

Comment: @Neil Updated the method in update 1. Please suggest.

Comment: @Neil.  The request will fail unless TLS 1.2 is used.  Microsoft recently did Security Update and disables TLS 1.0 and 1.1 in the operating system.  So existing code that worked two years ago will not work due to server refusing the request.  Bot the client and server have to be using the same version of TLS.  The OP is modifying Client code.  So if client send TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 the server will return an error.

Comment: @jdweng And what if the target environment is Windows 7 (or earlier) and have not been updated (say this is some sort of embedded system in a self contained laboratory that's not on the internet) ? Also, as far I as I can tell, even the latest versions of .netcore have the same problem (a sealed class with a private constructor) and therefore upgrading won't help with fix the actual question.

Comment: Net Core is the System Net Library and not the operating System.  I said in first posting "Also you must update any APIs (dll) to versions that support TLS 1.2."  What operating system are you using on client?  Core and Operating System has to be consistent.  And Core 2.1 May not have the TLS settings (which can be overridden).

Comment: @Neil, jdweng All external variables can be ignored since I have 2 projects side by side, one is instantiating properly, another is not, not sure about the difference. No external calls are made, just a mock AuthenticationResult object, how'll TLS help?

Comment: How is authentication performed?  If you want to compare working and non-working use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to compare.  TLS doesn't help except that authentication is using TLS.  So working is not using TLS while non-working is using TLS.

Comment: @jdweng, you have to understand that we don't care about the functionality while creating this dummy object. Think of it like our objective is creating a dummy AuthenticationResult object that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well it is giving you an exception.  How are you going to solve the issue.  All I've done is told why it is happening.  Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: What will happening when you deploy your changes?  Will it work?  Has anybody recently used your old version?  Does it still work?  The issue is not with Core but with the operating system.  When you upgrade the operating system to support TLS 1.2 you will probably have incompatibility issues.

Comment: @jdweng This is a unit test, no need to be concerned with what works , what doesn't. If you have knowledge, give the right way to initialize it.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netcore-3.1.  You need a class AuthenticationResult.  You also have to Read the Purple Section under REMARKS :  (See Security Considerations for Reflection.)

Comment: @jdweng I'm using Windows 10 and I'm using the AuthenticationResult class from here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.authenticationresult?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Your link is the results of the authentication.  Not the request.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplication.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Identity_Client_PublicClientApplication__ctor_System_String_